# Add image overlay on video FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video, `test.mp4`, and an image, `test.png`.

`test.png` is a black image with a transparent "hole" in the center.

I would like, using FFmpeg:

- To display `test.png` over the video so I can only see a circle of video
- If possible, to resize `test.png` to the size of the video so it covers the whole thing

Is this possible ?

Comment: Just a quick comment - if this is just to display on a web page then a much easier approach is just to put a 'mask' div over the video div. I am guessing this is not what you want and you actually want to produce a new video with the black surround, but just in case...

Comment: No indeed, I really want a video. But thanks for the comment Mick, I'm sure it can help others

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -framerate 30000/1001 -loop 1 -i test.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=out:st=30:d=1:alpha=1 [ov]; [0:v][ov] overlay=10:10 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest out.mp4
```

Comment: This helped me to overlay the image while properly mapping the audio of the input video to the output. Thanks

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. How could we set a size for png image on this command?

Comment: getting crash on this url

Answer (score 0):

I used this on android and its working fine :-

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{ "-i", video.mp4, "-i", image.png, "-filter_complex", "overlay=0:main_h-overlay_h", outputFile.getPath()};
```

Comment: Can you explain! how you did for Android application ??

Comment: just use this command , it will work . Video.mp4 is the video you want to add overly on. image.png is the image you want to add . outputfile is the video output. Also Read ffmpeg documentation .

Comment: is there any library i should include for my android project?

Comment: Shall we add image to video using this library??

Comment: @Hangman https://github.com/madhavanmalolan/ffmpegandroidlibrary/issues/28 can u tell solution for  this issue !!!!1

Comment: @Hangman  is there any possibility to detect faces while replacing an image??? or i should use face detection api ...

Comment: use face detection api