# Put image over video and save video to sd card Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm working on a feature in which I want to add picture over the video and save it to sd card.

in general, the user selects an image with semi-transparent background and puts that image above the video, after the user presses the save button he gets a new video but already with the image above the video.

I have heard about **ffmpeg**, and saw some commands that are provided by ffmpeg. but I don't know where I should initialize. can anyone provide me an example for the same?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One common approach is to use an ffmpeg wrapper to access ffmpeg functionality from your Android app.

There are several fairly well used wrappers available on GitHub - the ones below are particularly well featured and documented (note, I have not used these as they were not so mature when I was looking at this previously, but if I was doing something like this again now I would definitely build on one of these):

- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/
- https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Using one of the well supported and used libraries will take care of some common issues that you might otherwise encounter - having to load different binaries for different processor types, and some tricky issues with native library reloading to avoid crashes on subsequent invocations of the wrapper.

Because this approach uses the standard ffmpeg cmd line syntax for commands it also means you should be able to search and find help easily on multiple different operations (as anyone using ffmpeg in 'normal' model will use the same syntax for the ffmpeg command itself).

For example, for your adding an image case here are some results from a quick search (ffmpeg syntax can change over time so it is worth doing a current check):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32250369/334402
- https://superuser.com/a/678171