# ffmpeg: Is there a way to create video from images and overlay on image at same time?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video from still images using ffmpeg. The command I use to do this is

`ffmpeg -y -r 3 -i input_images%03d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=24 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4`

However, I would like to overlay this video on still image, without creating a video of the still image first. So, for example, if I have the following images

`[still, frame1, frame2, frame3]`

I'd like a command to create a video of frame1, frame2, and frame3 overlayed on still.

all with one command. Is there a way to do this?

I've looked at several answers to related problems (e.g., [Add image overlay on video FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674385/add-image-overlay-on-video-ffmpeg)) but they don't answer my question, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i still.png -framerate 3 -i input_images%03d.png -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "overlay=x='(W-w)/2':y='(H-h)/2'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4`

Comment: That's works! Thanks. Everything I tried before involved looping the still image. I guess not the right approach. Would you mind explaining the overlay part of the command?